# How to determine value of variable passed into a function in bash?

Tags: string, bash, shell

So I have a function that asks a user for some input, then uses `eval` to assign the value of the input to the variable name passed in. I.e.

```
eval "$1='$input'"
```

But I would like to check if `$1` is empty because if it isn't I don't want to re-assign it a value. This function is called multiple times, so it'd be best if I could just add some check in it without doing a check at each call.

I tried

```
if [[ ! -z "$1" ]]; then
    return
fi
```

But the variable `$1` evaluates to the variable name I passed into it.

I.e. `_function_call VAR_A` <- This call would result in `$1` being `VAR_A` if evaluated in the function.

So, is there any way I can determine the value of the variable, or just check if it is empty in the function? The function is not called from another function.

Comment: You can use `declare -g "$1=$input"` instead of eval. It's somewhat safer, and a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BASH indirection to first get the variable whose name is stored in `$1`:

```
var1=${!1}

# then
if [[ ! -z "$var1" ]]; then
   exit 1
fi
```